# Абстрактный List с интерфейсом

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Подскажите как реализовать абстрактный List<> который содержит интерфейсы? Компилятор ругается на `get { return arr; }`якобы разные типы.

```
abstract class TestClass 
{
    protected abstract List<IMyClass> ListWithInterface { get; }
}

class TestClass2 : TestClass
{
    List<MyClass> arr = new List<MyClass>();
    protected override List<IMyClass> ListWithInterface
    {
        get { return arr; }
    }
}

interface IMyClass
{
    int A { get; }
}

class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    int a;
    int IMyClass.A
    {
        get { return a; }
    }

    public MyClass(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ссылки, решил с помощью обобщения.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass2 testClass2 = new TestClass2();
        testClass2.Print();
    }
}

abstract class TestClass <T> where T : IMyClass
{
    protected abstract List<T> ListWithInterface { get; }

    internal void Print()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ListWithInterface.Count; i++)            
            Console.WriteLine(ListWithInterface[i].A);            
    }    
}

class TestClass2 : TestClass<MyClass2>
{
    List<MyClass2> arr = new List<MyClass2>() { new MyClass2(5) };
    protected override List<MyClass2> ListWithInterface
    {
        get { return arr; }
    }        
}

interface IMyClass
{
   int A { get; }
}

class MyClass2 : IMyClass
{
    int a;
    int IMyClass.A
    {
        get { return a; }
    }
    public MyClass2(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }       
}
```